# Netsuite - Saved Search Formula(text) Case statement multiply 2 fields

Tags: formula, netsuite, case-statement, saved-searches

I'm trying to get the product of 2 fields in the 'ELSE' portion of a CASE statement of a Formula(Text) row in a Netsuite saved search, but I keep getting 'ERROR: Invalid Expression' when I run the search.  Current formula is:

```
CASE WHEN {binonhandcount} = 0 THEN '0' ELSE NVL({binonhandcount}, 0) * NVL({locationaveragecost}, 0) END
```

I've tried to simplify it by doing something like this:

```
CASE WHEN {binonhandcount} = 0 THEN '0' ELSE 1 + 1 END
```

But it still fails with an invalid expression error.  All of the Googling I've done leads me to believe that this *should* work, but I can't seem to find my mistake.  I'm hoping the extra eyes here can give me a kick in the right direction.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type returned from the formula needs to match the Formula type selected.  You can correct your formula by setting it to a Formula (Numeric) type and simply removing the quotes around the '0' after the first `THEN`:

```
CASE WHEN {binonhandcount} = 0 THEN 0 ELSE NVL({binonhandcount}, 0) * NVL({locationaveragecost}, 0) END
```

Or if you really want a text formula for some reason, you can wrap the `ELSE` statement in a `TO_CHAR` function:

```
CASE WHEN {binonhandcount} = 0 THEN '0' ELSE TO_CHAR(NVL({binonhandcount}, 0) * NVL({locationaveragecost}, 0)) END
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had tried the numeric formula first but still had the quotes around the 0.

Answer (score 1):

In your NetSuite saved search replace Formula(text) to Formula(Numeric).

**And your formula would be:**

```
CASE WHEN {binonhandcount} = 0 THEN 0 ELSE NVL({binonhandcount}, 0) * NVL({locationaveragecost}, 0) END
```

Please remove the string from THEN '0'. You should be fine.